# Clojurscript: extend a Javascript class

Tags: clojurescript, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I'm trying to use a particular JavaScript framework which requires extending a base class to use it for application.

Basically I want to do the following as idiomatic ClojureScript.

```js
class Foo extends Bar {
  constructor() { super("data") }
  method1(args) { /* do stuff */ }
}
```

I tried

```clj
(defn foo
  []
  (reify
    js/Bar
    (constructor [this] (super this "data"))
    (method1 [this args] )))
```

Which would work if I'd create a new class from Object, but as `shadow-cljs` correctly complains, "Symbol js/Bar is not a protocol". Also, I don't want to add methods but create a subclass that inherits somemethods  and overloads others.

I thought about using `proxy`, but "core/proxy is not defined".

Of course I could create an instance of `Bar` and `set!` new methods, but that feels like giving up and using an inferior language.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Please see answer below for more current solution!**

CLJS has no built-in support for `class ... extends ...`.

You can hack it together yourself with a bit of boilerplate, which you could generate via a macro to make it look pretty.

```clj
(ns your.app
  (:require
    [goog.object :as gobj]
    ["something" :refer (Bar)]))

(defn Foo
  {:jsdoc ["@constructor"]}
  []
  (this-as this
    (.call Bar this "data")
    ;; other constructor work
    this))

(gobj/extend
  (.-prototype Foo)
  (.-prototype Bar)
  ;; defining x.foo(arg) method
  #js {:foo (fn [arg]
              (this-as this
                ;; this is Foo instance
                ))})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a pity there is no built-in facility for that, but that will finally give me a reason to read deeper into macros.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the `Class constructor L cannot be invoked without 'new'` issue when using this method?

My current workaround is creating stub JS files containing `export default class Foo extends Bar {}` for each class, importing them, and using `gobj/extend` to define the actual functionality in CLJS. It works, but the folder of JS stubs is clunky and a bit error prone.

Comment: Not sure I have seen that error message before. I know there are some issues when trying to extend native built-in classes (eg. `HTMLElement`) which require working with `Reflect` in some way but I can't remember the details.

Comment: The specific error is likely a result of `:output-feature-set :es6`, which I have to use in turn to avoid the Closure compiler error `ES6 transpilation of 'assigning to a super property' is not yet implemented` being caused by a library I'm using. I'll look further into using `Reflect` and see if that can help here - thanks very much for the pointer and the quick reply. Worst case the JS stub files still work, I just hope we don't start to see the ES6 ecosystem leaving us behind!

Answer (score 12):

CLJS (still) has no built-in support for `class ... extends ...`.

However in recent `shadow-cljs` versions I added support for `class` as well as `extends`. This will emit a standard JS `class` and does not require any hacky workarounds to get it working.

Translating this example

```js
class Foo extends Bar {
  constructor() { super("data") }
  method1(args) { /* do stuff */ }
}
```

would be

```clj
(ns your.app
  (:require [shadow.cljs.modern :refer (defclass)]))

(defclass Foo
  ;; extends takes a symbol argument, referencing the super class
  ;; could be a local symbol such as Bar
  ;; a namespaced symbol such as alias/Bar
  ;; or just a global via js/Bar
  (extends Bar)

  (constructor [this]
    (super "data"))

  ;; adds regular method, protocols similar to deftype/defrecord also supported
  Object
  (method1 [this args]
    ;; do stuff
    ))
```

More complex examples of `defclass` can be found [here](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-experiments/blob/master/src/main/shadow/experiments/grove/components.cljs#L159) and [here](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-experiments/blob/master/src/main/shadow/experiments/grove/ui/vlist.cljs#L26).

Currently this only ships with shadow-cljs but technically you can take the `modern.cljc` and `modern.cljs` files from [here](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs/tree/master/src/main/shadow/cljs) and put them into your project. It should work with all build tools then.

Comment: This is quite interesting. I was going through the implementation [here](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs/blob/master/src/main/shadow/cljs/modern.cljc) and was pleasantly surprised by how extensible the CLJS compiler is. Might be a while (or never) before this would be supported by the compiler natively.


Have you consider publishing it as a separate library?

Comment: Not at this time, but feel free to take the two files and make your own library. Just change the namespace please.

Comment: How do I call super.method1() from overloaded method1 ?